# solving a PDE with with coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

First i need to find eigenfunctions in spherical coordinates with source term.

I am having trouble with this . Can someone help guide me

i also have 2 b.c.'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenfunctions are $\sin \left( {\frac {\beta_{{n}}r}{R}} \right)$ where $\beta_{{n}}$ are the roots of

$\sin \left( \beta_{{n}} \right) =\beta_{{n}}\cos \left( \beta_{{n}}
 \right) 
$;

We look for a solution of

${\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}w \left( r,t \right) =\alpha\,{\frac {
\partial ^{2}}{\partial {r}^{2}}}w \left( r,t \right) +rg \left( r,t
 \right) 
$

with the form

$w \left( r,t \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }A_{{n}} \left( t \right) 
\sin \left( {\frac {\beta_{{n}}r}{R}} \right) 
$

$rg \left( r,t \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }B_{{n}} \left( t \right) 
\sin \left( {\frac {\beta_{{n}}r}{R}} \right) 
$

Then we obtain

${\frac {d}{dt}}A_{{n}} \left( t \right) =-{\frac {\alpha\,A_{{n}}
 \left( t \right) {\beta_{{n}}}^{2}-B_{{n}} \left( t \right) {R}^{2}}{
{R}^{2}}}
$

Using the method of the integrating factor the last equation is rewritten as

${{\rm e}^{-{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}t}{{R}^{2}}}}}{\frac {
\partial }{\partial t}} \left( A_{{n}} \left( t \right) {{\rm e}^{{
\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}t}{{R}^{2}}}}} \right) =B_{{n}}
 \left( t \right) 
$

or as

${{\rm e}^{-{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}}{\frac {
\partial }{\partial \tau}} \left( A_{{n}} \left( \tau \right) {{\rm e}
^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}} \right) =B_{{n}}
 \left( \tau \right) 
$

From this we deduce that

${\frac {\partial }{\partial \tau}} \left( A_{{n}} \left( \tau \right) 
{{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}} \right) =
B_{{n}} \left( \tau \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2
}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}}
$

integrating both sides we have

$\int _{0}^{t}\!{\frac {\partial }{\partial \tau}} \left( A_{{n}}
 \left( \tau \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{
{R}^{2}}}}} \right) {d\tau}=\int _{0}^{t}\!B_{{n}} \left( \tau
 \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}}{
d\tau}
$

and then we obtain

$A_{{n}} \left( t \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}t}
{{R}^{2}}}}}-A_{{n}} \left( 0 \right) =\int _{0}^{t}\!B_{{n}} \left( 
\tau \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}
}}}{d\tau}
$

it is to say

$A_{{n}} \left( t \right) = \left( \int _{0}^{t}\!B_{{n}} \left( \tau
 \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}}{
d\tau}+A_{{n,0}} \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}t
}{{R}^{2}}}}}
$

where $A_{n,0}=A_{n}(0)$

Then we have

$w \left( r,t \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(  \left( \int _{0}^{
t}\!B_{{n}} \left( \tau \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}
}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}}{d\tau}+A_{{n,0}} \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {
\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}t}{{R}^{2}}}}}\sin \left( {\frac {\beta_{{n}}
r}{R}} \right)  \right) 
$

and

$F \left( r,t \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(  \left( \int _{0}^{
t}\!B_{{n}} \left( \tau \right) {{\rm e}^{{\frac {\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}
}^{2}\tau}{{R}^{2}}}}}{d\tau}+A_{{n,0}} \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {
\alpha\,{\beta_{{n}}}^{2}t}{{R}^{2}}}}}\sin \left( {\frac {\beta_{{n}}
r}{R}} \right)  \right) {r}^{-1}
$

Comment: Ok, the only last part i am confused on is integrating factor part..i do not see how you came to your answer with integrating factor.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this answer equivalent to other with the Bromwich integral?

Comment: You are welcome.  Please note the advantage of the Laplace transform method that it does not need the integrating factor but the dis-advantage is the Laplace transform needs the Bromwich integral.

Comment: any ideas here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055041/nonlinear-differential-equation-zero-and-first-order-solutions